# How can I add a bottom margin to an absolutely positioned div?

Tags: css, margin, css-position

I have a div along the left side of my webpage that expands to varying heights depending on its contents. Sometimes its inner contents causes the div to expand to the bottom of the page. However, I want there to be a margin at the bottom, so it doesn't actually go to the bottom of the page. How can I add the necessary margin? I tried adding `margin-bottom:50px` to `.wrap`, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">Contents</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    min-width:220px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. I tried that solution and it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `bottom:50px;` to .wrap div. you positioned div so you can set position by left,right,top,bottom. It will be always 50px up from bottom.

```
.wrap {
position:absolute;
top:40px;
min-width:220px;
left:0;
bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank, but the problem with this is that I don't always want the div to be 50px from the bottom. I just want it to never be closer than 50px from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had `overflow:hidden;` in the class `wrap`. That was the problem.